# Fetch records based on variable declared in a column in DB2

Tags: db2

Is there a way to fetch records which contains the variable declared against getMboSet and does NOT have close(), For example below is the example table and should return second row as  getMboSet's variable xyzSet does not have has xyzSet.close() however the first row has abcSet.close()

```
 Name           Source 
 Test           abcSet=MXServer().getMboSet("HELLO", mbo.getUserInfo())
                abcSet = abcSet.getMbo(0)
                abcSet.close()
 Demo           xyzSet=MXServer().getMboSet("WELCOME", mbo.getUserInfo())
                xyzSet = xyzSet.getMbo(0)
```